# Why data does not match when JOIN same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display the table like this

Desired Result:
[image: Desired result]

With the conditions:

1. tgl1, kondisi_1, kondisi_2, kondisi_3, kondisi_4 is latest condition group by kd_item
2. tgl2, kond1, kond2, kond3, kond4 is latest data where date <= CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY group by kd_item

SQL:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/661f7/2

I try to write the query like this,

Query:

```
SELECT a.kd_item, MAX(a.tanggal) as tgl1, a.kondisi_1, a.kondisi_2, a.kondisi_3, a.kondisi_4,
-- I know min is not the right query 
MIN(b.tanggal) as tgl2, b.kondisi_1 as kond1, b.kondisi_2 as kond2, b.kondisi_3 as kond3, b.kondisi_4 as kond4
FROM status_item as a
LEFT JOIN status_item as b ON a.kd_item = b.kd_item
GROUP BY a.kd_item LIMIT 10
```

1. When I am joining same table, with the above query, why is the displayed data not related with the date?
2. How to display date with condition latest date where date less then or equal with 7 days ago?
3. How to display point 2 at left side of the table?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should select the max date, join with the data for get column non involved  in group by  and then join the two different query toghter

```
select * from (
  select a.kd_item, a.tanggal as tgl1, a.kondisi_1, a.kondisi_2, a.kondisi_3, a.kondisi_4
  from status_item a 
  inner join (
    SELECT kd_item, MAX(tanggal) as max_tanggal
    FROM status_item 
    group by kd_item
    ) t1 on t1.max_tanggal = a.tanggal and t1.kd_item = a.kd_item
) t3 
inner join (
  select b.kd_item, b.tanggal as b_tgl1, b.kondisi_1 as b_kondisi_1, b.kondisi_2 as b_kondisi_2 , b.kondisi_3 as b_kondisi_3, b.kondisi_4 as b_kondisi_4
  from status_item b 
  inner join (
    SELECT kd_item, MAX(tanggal) as max_tanggal
    FROM status_item 
    where tanggal <= date_sub(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
    group by kd_item
  ) t2 on t2.max_tanggal = b.tanggal and t2.kd_item = b.kd_item
) t4 on t3.kd_item= t4.kd_item
```

Comment: I edit the code and fix.. thanks you so much... i edit your query with this
where tanggal <= CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY and 
t2 on t2.max_tanggal = b.tanggal and t2.kd_item = b.kd_item

Comment: @GopurS  many thanks for the right editing and fix

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select
    a.kd_item, 
    a.tanggal  as tgl1, 
    a.kondisi_1, 
    a.kondisi_2, 
    a.kondisi_3, 
    a.kondisi_4,
    b.tanggal   as tgl2, 
    b.kondisi_1 as kond1, 
    b.kondisi_2 as kond2, 
    b.kondisi_3 as kond3, 
    b.kondisi_4 as kond4
from
    status_item as a
    left join 
    status_item as b 
    on
        a.kd_item = b.kd_item and
        b.tanggal <= date_sub(a.tanggal, interval 7 day);
```

The results are:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| kd_item | tgl1       | kondisi_1 | kondisi_2 | kondisi_3 | kondisi_4 | tgl2       | kond1 | kond2 | kond3 | kond4 |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       1 | 2017-10-22 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | 2017-10-07 |     3 |     0 |     1 |     0 |
|       1 | 2017-10-17 |         3 |         1 |         0 |         0 | 2017-10-07 |     3 |     0 |     1 |     0 |
|       2 | 2017-12-22 |         3 |         0 |         1 |         0 | 2017-12-12 |     2 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
|       2 | 2017-12-22 |         3 |         0 |         1 |         0 | 2017-10-22 |     4 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|       2 | 2017-12-12 |         2 |         1 |         0 |         1 | 2017-10-22 |     4 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|       3 | 2017-12-12 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | 2017-10-22 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|       8 | 2017-12-06 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | 2017-11-28 |     0 |     0 |     4 |     0 |
|       1 | 2017-10-07 |         3 |         0 |         1 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       2 | 2017-10-22 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       3 | 2017-10-22 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       4 | 2017-10-22 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       5 | 2017-10-27 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       5 | 2017-10-22 |         3 |         0 |         1 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       6 | 2017-10-22 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       7 | 2017-10-22 |         4 |         0 |         0 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
|       8 | 2017-11-28 |         0 |         0 |         4 |         0 | null       |  null |  null |  null |  null |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For point 3 in your question, you could add

```
date_sub(a.tanggal, interval 7 day)
```

as the first result column:

```
select
    date_sub(a.tanggal, interval 7 day) as week_ago,
    a.kd_item, 
    a.tanggal  as tgl1, 
    ...
```

Comment: hi thank you, but the result table that i want is not like that, you can see the result table in the above question..

Comment: I see.  I misread the question, and it has been edited now, so I'll have another look.